# Batch code doesn't update record

Tags: apex, batch, error, update

I have the batch code seen below.  It does run, however it does not update the record (Shipping Status) that I want it to update.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
global class TrackingUpdateScheduled implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    global final String query;
    global final String s_object;
    global final String field_from;
    global final String field_to;
    global final String field_value;

    global TrackingUpdateScheduled(String q, String s, String f1, String f){
        q = 'select Tracking,Shipping_Status from ShippingTest';
        s = 'ShippingTest__c';
        f = 'Tracking';
        f1 = 'Shipping_Status';
        Query = q;
        s_object = s;
        field_from = f;
        field_to = f1;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sOBject> scope){
        for(sObject o : scope){
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String TrackingNumber = field_from;
        req.setEndpoint('http://www.boxoh.com/?t=' + TrackingNumber);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        XmlStreamReader reader = res.getXmlStreamReader();
        String konnor = res.getBody();
        konnor = konnor.replace('>','> ');
        konnor = konnor.replace('<',' <');
        String ShipmentStatus = '';
        set<string> a=new Set<string>{'Delivered','Picked Up'};
        List<String> lsttest=konnor.split(' ');
        for(String s: lsttest){
            if(a.contains('Delivered')){
                ShipmentStatus = 'Delivered';
                o.put(field_to, ShipmentStatus);
            } else if(a.contains('Picked Up')) {
                ShipmentStatus = 'Picked Up';
                o.put(field_to, ShipmentStatus);
            }
        }
        update scope;
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

Also I run the batch via

```
String q = 'select Tracking,Shipping_Status from ShippingTest';
String s = 'ShippingTest__c';
String f = 'Tracking';
String f1 = 'Shipping_Status';
batchinstanceid = Database.executeBatch(new TrackingUpdateScheduled(q,s,f1,f));
```

**UPDATE:**

```
global class AnotherTest implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts{

global String query;
global String field_from;
global String field_to;

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   String query = 'select Tracking__c,Shipping_Status__c from ShippingTest__c'; 
   String field_from = 'Tracking__c';
   String field_to = 'Shipping_Status__c';
   return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
    for(sObject o : scope){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    String TrackingNumber = field_from;
    req.setEndpoint('http://www.boxoh.com/?t=' + TrackingNumber);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug(res.getBody());
    XmlStreamReader reader = res.getXmlStreamReader();
    String konnor = res.getBody();
    konnor = konnor.replace('>','> ');
    konnor = konnor.replace('<',' <');
    String ShipmentStatus = '';
    set<string> a=new Set<string>{'Delivered','Picked Up'};
    List<String> lsttest=konnor.split(' ');
    for(String s: lsttest){
        if(a.contains('Delivered')){
            ShipmentStatus = 'Delivered';
            o.put(field_to, ShipmentStatus);
            system.debug('Delivered');
        } else if(a.contains('Picked Up')) {
            ShipmentStatus = 'Picked Up';
            o.put(field_to, ShipmentStatus);
            system.debug('Picked Up');
        } else {
            ShipmentStatus = 'Error';
            o.put(field_to, ShipmentStatus);
            system.debug('Error');
        }
    }
    update scope;
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

}
}
```

Comment: I do not think you execute method is being ran thus no records are returned in the query. If your execute method was being ran then you would get a max callout 1 error since you did not implement Database.AllowsCallout. Also what are all those properties you are setting but are never used? (s_object for example). Do you even have any shipping test records?

Comment: And why are you changing the variables passed in i.e. `s` it just does not make any sense...I am assuming that you have just copied and pasted some code and added your own and are trying to get it to work. If that is the case see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are using all that stuff for but it can be reduced to this:

```
global class TrackingUpdateScheduled implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       String query = 'select Tracking,Shipping_Status from ShippingTest'; 
       return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sOBject> scope){
        for(sObject o : scope){

          global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
            for(sObject o : scope){
                Http http = new Http();
                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

                req.setEndpoint('http://www.boxoh.com/?t=' + (String)o.get('Tracking__c'));
                req.setMethod('GET');

                HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        system.debug(logginglevel.error,req.getEndpoint());

                System.debug(res.getBody());
                XmlStreamReader reader = res.getXmlStreamReader();
                String konnor = res.getBody();
                konnor = konnor.replace('>','> ');
                konnor = konnor.replace('<',' <');
                String ShipmentStatus = '';
                set<string> a=new Set<string>{'Delivered','Picked Up'};
                List<String> lsttest=konnor.split(' ');

                for(String s: lsttest){
                    if(a.contains('Delivered')){
                        ShipmentStatus = 'Delivered';
                        o.put('Shipping_Status__c', ShipmentStatus);
                        system.debug('Delivered');
                    } else if(a.contains('Picked Up')) {
                        ShipmentStatus = 'Picked Up';
                        o.put('Shipping_Status__c', ShipmentStatus);
                        system.debug('Picked Up');
                    } else {
                        ShipmentStatus = 'Error';
                        o.put('Shipping_Status__c', ShipmentStatus);
                        system.debug('Error');
                    }
                }
            }
        }  

        update scope;


    }


    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

Then simply run it as such:

```
TrackingUpdateScheduled b = new TrackingUpdateScheduled();
database.executeBatch(b,1); //Shange scope as needed
```

Comment: Sorry. I am clearly no expert at this. There were some variables that were not being used simply because I had intentions for them, before I inserted the code I had previously made, that eventually faded away. I do have a ShippingTest__c object, the Tracking field and the Shipping Status field, and I have multiple different example records.  However, even with the code above in UPDATE, Shipping Status is still not changed.  I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: did you look at what you received back from the callout? maybe it does not meet and if the if logic and thus never updated. add some debugs and check the values

Comment: callout is not returning anything, neither are my debugs.  However, the new 'update' I posted above is the only script I can get to run.  Otherwise I get errors such as: Invalid type: Database.AllowsCallout, and __c errors which are relatively easy to fix.

Comment: It should be Database.AllowsCallouts. Change that then your callout should work.

Comment: I'm confused, that's exactly what I have above? Just noticed my typo in the comment, not the code, sorry.

Comment: I was just answering your comment. Debug the `res` itself. Check the status code, debug what you are getting. The fact that you are getting there means it must be an issue with your callout

Comment: It seems you are setting your tracking number to the string `Tracking__c` (Which is not a valid tracking number) It should be `(String)o.get('field_from');` should it not? Debug your request and you will see whats wrong.

Comment: I tested the callout by itself and it's giving me the xml response and the "DEBUG|Delivered" which is what I want to see.  Although I could be wrong, from what I see there is a problem getting the response to the record, considering the batch runs and I get a debug when the two codes are separate, but not when they are together.  Should I have the callout in a separate class by itself and try to run it from the batch?  If so is there a way I can do that without having a void method and/or not using cases?

Comment: Testing it yourself does not test what you are sending. You ARE NOT sending the correct information. 'Tracking__c' is not a valid tracking number. It is good that you can do it manually now replicate that in your code

Comment: I fixed Tracking__c. And by testing it myself I meant I tested the separate code, and did again with (String)o.get('field_from');.  Also, in the logs it notes that a variable assestment says that "ShippingStatus|"Delivered"" so my interpretation of that is that the variable is being correctly assigned but the delivery to the record is not functioning properly.

Comment: Look at my updated code. Your other issue may be that the batch error on the second callout as you did DML inside the loop. Which would have caused an error and a rollback. Try what I posted and do some debugging. You will get it. Its hard to quarterback when you cannot debug yourself

Comment: I'm getting null errors, hold on. Line 33, Column 1

Comment: So debug errors say that 'Shipping_Status__c' is null, when it however, is not...

Comment: Everything works great now, except for the fact that everything is registering 'delivered' when I know one test tracking number should specifically say Picked Up.  Is it because I'm using a string for the query and not a list?  If so is there a way for me to run the batch at a limit of 1 for each record instead of having to change my code?  If not will I have to change it to be Iterable?

Comment: Yes. Set the scope size to 1 database.execute(b,1). But your code should be updated to handle bulk records anyways

Comment: And if my answer worked then please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: I'm still a bit confused.  One test record has a tracking number that should return 'Picked up' whereas the other has a test record that should return 'Delivered'.  Instead, I can either get both records to display 'Error' or both records to display 'Delivered', if I simply change some variables... Is it not processing the callout for each record?

Comment: If you set the batch size to 1 as in my example you can review the debug logs for each batch (which will be 1 for each record). This it will be easier to debug. This is a debugging exercise to inspect your data at the critical points, then reasoning as to why it may not be correct. Maybe it is your code, maybe it is your data. A Scope size of 1 will yield a separate transaction / log for each shipping test record